# Caching usable in both WCF and ASP .NET applications (.NET 3.5)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, caching

I need caching facility which should work from both WCF and from within an ASP .NET app. I have seen:

1. `System.Web.Caching.Cache` which is not usable from WCF (as I understand it is usable only if service is hosted in IIS, which is not always the case)
2. `System.Runtime.Caching` which is usable from both of them, but only available from .NET 4, but our .NET version is 3.5.

Any suggestions?

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7849068/559144

Comment: @DavidePiras thanks for the suggestion . but my requirement cannot afford something like AppFabric . Do you know of any facilities in .NET itself to solve the problem ?

Comment: Are you looking for an out of process distributed cache to be available for both IIS and windows services running on the same server or what exactly? do you need to share the cache content among different processes in same or different machines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can absolutely use `System.Web.Caching.Cache` outside of IIS. Just add a reference to `System.Web` and away you go - it is absolutely not a feature of IIS.

There were issues in .NET 1.0 and 1.1 but apparently not in 2.0 and upwards - see [this Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917411).

But like Davide Piras I would also recommend considering AppFabric to share the cache between your two applications, if that would be useful. I'm not sure what you mean by "my requirement cannot afford something like AppFabric" - by "afford" are you talking about performance, memory, or what? Whilst AppFabric is designed to be used on a cache server it does not by any means require dedicated hardware, you can run the service on the same box as your application if you need to.

Comment: thanks carson . by Appfabric not being "affordable" , i mean i dont intend to use this as a general purpose caching solution in my application . I just need a simple solution for caching a bunch of configs to avoid hitting the db . the scope is limited ..

Comment: @theneoindian: fair enough. In that case, definitely just use `System.Web.Caching.Cache`, it will do the job for you.

Comment: Have a look at AppFabric caching. It will allow you to share a cache between ASP.NET and WCF. Even if both are hosted on different servers. This cache requires at least .NET 3.5.

For WCF see the following article:
http://pieterderycke.wordpress.com/2012/08/28/caching-in-wcf-services-part-2-appfabric-distributed-cache/

For ASP.NET:
http://www.cshandler.com/2011/07/using-window-server-appfabric-for.html

Answer (score 1):

new solution use Windows Server AppFabric Caching

https://github.com/geersch/AppFabric

http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/caching-wcf-services-part-2

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2012/AAP314

***2.in .NET 1.0 and 1.1 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917411