# what is best solution for share cache in multi application

Tags: caching

The standard .NET 4.0 cache cannot be shared among multiple servers.I need share cache in multi application, what is best solution for share cache in multi application
I need help for this problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can absolutely use System.Web.Caching.Cache outside of IIS. Just add a reference to System.Web and away you go - it is absolutely not a feature of IIS

The [System.Web.Caching.Cache object is not intended for use outside ASP.NET in the .NET Framework 1.1 and in the .NET Framework 1.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917411?wa=wsignin1.0).

Comment: Have a look at AppFabric caching. It will allow you to share a cache between ASP.NET and WCF. Even if both are hosted on different servers. This cache requires at least .NET 3.5. For WCF see the following article: pieterderycke.wordpress.com/2012/08/28/… For ASP.NET: cshandler.com/2011/07/using-window-server-appfabric-for.html

Answer (score 0):

A couple of months ago, I wrote an article about caching in WCF using the in-process memory cache available in the .NET 4.0 framework. This component offers a lightweight caching solution that can easily be integrated in various types of .NET applications.

There are scenarios where a more advanced caching solution is required. The standard .NET 4.0 cache cannot be shared among multiple servers. Every server has its own isolated instance of the cache. Furthermore, it shares memory with the application. A 32-bit application can allocate at maximum 4 GB of RAM (on a 64-bit OS; maximum 2GB of RAM on a 32-bit OS). There can be situations where you want that the cache of a 32-bit app is larger than 2 GB (although these situations are rare).

new solution use Windows Server AppFabric Caching

https://github.com/geersch/AppFabric

http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/caching-wcf-services-part-2

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2012/AAP314

[Caching usable in both WCF and ASP .NET applications (.NET 3.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686728/caching-usable-in-both-wcf-and-asp-net-applications-net-3-5/14172721#14172721)